# How to see the source code of an application in android

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there any way to see the souce code of an application from the app. i tried this method by using the apk ectractor to extract the apk file from an application but i cant find any src file when i convert the apk file to zip. there only the res file which has all the xml files. i need the src file which has all the java file in it to see how the application work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following reverse engineering processes

1. using [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) decompile your apk file to
2. using [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) convert dex into normal Java jar files.
3. now you can do any of two
   a. use [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to decode the jar to java source. or
   b. extract the jar using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to class files and then use [cavaj](http://download.cnet.com/Cavaj-Java-Decompiler/3000-2213_4-10071619.html) to decode to java files

There must be other tool which you can find by search

useful links: [see this](http://kkinder.com/2011/11/27/so-you-want-to-reverse-engineer-an-android-app-apk/)

Comment: Thanks too for the tip!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the apk/zip it can contain java classes, or a .dex file.
 if it contains the .dex file, first you need to extract the clases from it (search online for a dex class extractor) and then when you get the actual java clases, you'll also need a java decompiler to be able to get to the source code from these classes.